# Reply after a given delay

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I would like to implement an simple timer within a communication.

My scenario is a small math trainer where you train 5 minutes, after the 5 minutes of normal interaction I would like to inform the user that the time is now up. I don't want to wait until the user has finished his next input/answer (optional just if there is currently no input).

Is there any way to "push" an answer time based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Conversation API does not support a push model. When you get the users response, you can check the timer and respond appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for this official answer. Is such a push message option planed?

Comment: I can't comment on future features planned, but we are very interested to get feedback like this from developers.

Comment: A push model seems very applicable to me. For instance, if you wanted to have app that warned the user to bring an umbrella on a forecasted rainy day. Rather than have a user say, "do I have to bring an umbrella today?"

Comment: @DannySullivan That would be pretty dangerous and hard to implement functionality and I think Google's choice to limit those kind of push notifications to just some high priority things (flights changes and the like) which they are 100% the user wants to see was a very wise choice. This question is more about 'I want to alert the user after a while during the same conversation'.

Comment: @LeonNicholls In one use case of mine I need to run some more complex stuff on the backend which can take up to a few minutes, so I would like to first answer 'Working on it' and then a minute later the actual response. Obviously if the user exits the conversation he would never hear that anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it looks like they are not interested in adding any sort of delay features:
[Dialogflow (API.AI) Forums :- Adding a delay to responses, so it feels more real](https://discuss.api.ai/t/adding-a-delay-to-responses-so-it-feels-more-real/108)

But this is one reason why building a server side solution in between your deployment integration (ex. Facebook messenger) and API.ai is so useful- it let's you customize fulfillments, including sending fulfillments triggered by your own custom logic built on top of API.ai solutions.

So in the case of FB messenger as a simple example, you could do something like below, and just build any logic you want to call sendTextMessage:

```js
function sendTextMessage(recipientId, text) {
    sendTypingOff(recipientId)
    var messageData = {
        recipient: {
            id: recipientId
        },
        message: {
            text: text
        }
    }
    callSendAPI(messageData);
}

//Calls FB messenger API. If successful returns a message ID in response
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
    request({
        uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
        qs: {
            access_token: config.FB_PAGE_TOKEN
        },
        method: 'POST',
        json: messageData

    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
            var messageId = body.message_id;

            if (messageId) {
                console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s",
                    messageId, recipientId);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s",
                    recipientId);
            }
        } else {
            console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably irrelevant for you by now but I'm writing an answer for people who might visit here.

You can implement this with `events` in Dialogflow (formerly API.ai). See [here for documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/events).
You define an intent based on an event called, say, `time-is-up`, and have a timer on your end that triggers this event after five minutes.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger an event via fulfillment, but outside an intent handler?